# css code to make the content not scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the fixed row as a last line in the scollable table. The row can be outside the table but fixed to the table and it should not scroll when user scoll's the table. I tried using below css code but couldn't fix the issue. The row highlighted in red color i want to make it fixed and when user scrolls it shoudn't scroll and should be seen.

css code:

```
 #foo {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background: red;
    }
```

Comment: make this a snippet

Comment: What is "the row highlighted in red color"? What element has an id of `foo`? You need to show HTML in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript in this instance.

The fix is more like a notification, i'd google css notification tricks or notifications javascript tricks.

I go with a simple 2 or 3 second timer with a fade & out & delete option.

---

### - OR -

use Javascript to change the className of the Item you just made the fix to.
ClassName is HTML class, which is CSS so you can do red or whatever.  You can even use a setTimeout function to make the color red fade away too.

Example

```js
var SET_TIMEOUT = {};
var countdown = 1;

function update_fix(_THIS_){
  _THIS_.parentNode.style.background='rgba(230, 25, 25, '+countdown+')';
  SET_TIMEOUT['color_fade()'] = setTimeout(function(){color_fade(_THIS_);}, 2000);
}

function color_fade(_THIS_){
  countdown = countdown - .01;
  _THIS_.parentNode.style.background='rgba(230, 25, 25, '+countdown+')';
  if(countdown!=0){
  SET_TIMEOUT['color_fade()'] = setTimeout(function(){color_fade(_THIS_);}, 20);
}}
```

```html
<TABLE CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=1 border=1 STYLE='width:80%;'>
<TR><TD>1
<TR><TD>2
<TR><TD>3
<TR><TD>4
<TR><TD>5
<TR><TD>6<INPUT type=button value='click to test' onclick=update_fix(this);>
<TR><TD>7
<TR><TD>8
<TR><TD>9
<TR><TD>10
<TR><TD>11
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use #foo css, Try this instead, If it helps then you can make css class yourself afterwards:

```
<center>
  <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; background-color: red; width: 100%;">
    <span style="width:35%;float: left;">fixed</span>
    <span style="width:15%;text-align: center;">sdf fixed</span>
    <span style="width:15%;float: right;">frw fixed</span>
  </div> 
</center>
```

Hope It'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
#foo {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `<tfoot>` tag

```
<tfoot>
  <tr id="foo">
    <td style="width:35%;text-align: center;" >fixed</td>
    <td style="width:15%;text-align: center; " >
      sdf fixed
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;text-align: center;">
      frw fixed
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

and it will be fixed on the foot, but you will need to change the fixed height of the table body.

Here is how it will be with your example

https://plnkr.co/edit/KoJcY4TxZS3DJeYgnbcs?p=preview